# JSF checkbox value not sent to bean

Tags: jsf, richfaces, javabeans

While the view can get all values from the bean, when a checkbox (`h:selectBooleanCheckbox`) is toggled the bean is not updated. The `setSelected()` method in `Item` is never called from the view.

I've tried changing the scope of the bean to application, using a map instead of a value for the selected property and a foolish attempt at writing my own ajax javascript function.

The application I'm working with is a bit legacy so I'm using Tomcat 6, JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3.3.Final.

It seems like it should be simple, I think I'm missing something obvious, but I've been at this for two days and can't figure out why the bean isn't updated.

My view is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<head>
<title>JSF</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h:form id="tableForm">
            <rich:dataTable id="table" value="#{managedBean}" var="item" width="100%">
                <rich:column label="Select" align="center" width="40px" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Select" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.selected}" >
                        <a4j:support execute="@this" event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column label="Name" align="center" width="40px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a managed bean ItemBean in session scope:

```
import org.richfaces.model.ExtendedTableDataModel;
public class ItemBean extends ExtendedTableDataModel<Item>{
    public ItemBean() {super(new ItemProvider());}
}
```

ItemProvider is:

```
import org.richfaces.model.DataProvider;

public class ItemProvider implements DataProvider<Item>{

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public ItemProvider(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            items.add(new Item(i, "Item "+i));
        }
    }

    public Item getItemByKey(Object key) {return items.get((Integer)key);}

    public List<Item> getItemsByRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return new ArrayList<Item>(items.subList(fromIndex, toIndex));
    }

    public Object getKey(Item arg0) {return arg0.getId();}

    public int getRowCount() {return items.size();}
}
```

and Items are:

```
public class Item {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Item(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected(){
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I hadn't set up my web.xml properly.

I was missing the following which routes the request to richfaces:

```
  <filter>
  <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume, that your vanilla `html`, `head` and `body` tags might cause this.

Ajax-stuff (javascript) sometimes has to go into the `<head>` section of the page (along with required script references). Because JSF is working with components, it needs to insert the javascript required for a certain component at the time the component is added to the underlaying Object-Model.

Therefore JSF itself needs to manage the `html`, `head` and `body` tags.

So, instead of creating them as vanilla-html, use the proper`<h:html>`, `<h:body>` and `<h:head>` tags, which will handover this task to JSF. This way, the required javascript code for your onclick-event handler should be generated and the checkbox should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately the issue was that I'd missed configuration in web.xml. Is it best practice to use the tags in your answer when working in JSF? It seems like it would be.